# CSS elements are displayed differently in different websites. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, styles

So I have an extension which creats a div and injects it as innerHTML to the currently opened page. Then there are different css elements in this div. Like buttons. However, same css elements are shown differently in different websites. Let me give an example of the different displays.

- Google shows it like this: 
  [image]
- w3schools shows it like this: 
  [image]

Even though the same code is run, the display is different. One text is bold while the other is not. And this is only one example. Another thing that happens is, table borders are shown in a website but are shown in another.
Like this:
Doing it like this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "extra_div";
div.innerHTML = myHTML;
document.body.append(div);
```

and myHTML is this:

```
var myHTML = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${chrome.runtime.getURL("myCSS.css")}">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>

<body>
<div id="myDiv">
    <button title="Ice Cream">Ice Cream</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am guessing it is because of the current websites' CSS options. Thus I am asking is there a way to prevent this? Or maybe something to say, "ignore every other css other than the code" etc.?

Comment: Please update the question with your code.

Comment: @m4n0 I have done it

Comment: Websites are using CSS normalizer or [CSS reset files](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to make pages to look and behave similarly on different browsers. There are a lot of commonly used reset files, and some sites use their own.

Comment: @Teemu so I am looking at this. But there's a small problem. When I use the reset file, the website I am in gets affected too. For example I was in Google.com and the links' fonts changed. But I only want to effect the div I inject, not the web page itself

Comment: @codertryer Than you'll need modify the reset file to affect only your div...